# Who Provides Sugar free chocolate?

Tags: chocolate

My grandfather loves chocolate so much but he has a diebites so i want to buy a sygar free chocolate for him so anyone tell me from where i can buy it.

Comment: As Maurizio mentioned, this question is practically unanswerable. I can find sweetened non-glycemic chocolate in the next drugstore, but this won't help you any if you live on another continent. We are already split on the question whether we allow sourcing questions, and hold them to even higher standards than usual (http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-types-of-sourcing-questions-should-be-allowed-revisit-march-2013-plea); it is likely that this question will be closed, but editing it might give it a chance.

Comment: I vote to close because we don't have a location + I don't have the feeling OP *tried* at least somewhere first.

Comment: Sourcing questions are troubling in general, and while we have no clear consensus, this is one where a general google search (shows sufficient research) should be able to provide an answer.


Comment: I came here to ask if I will be able to find chocolate that is sugar and artificial sweeteners (like maltitol) free. Now I am afraid to ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you live in the UK, Thorntons do a very good range of sugar free chocolates. My grandma says that these are the best ones she has tasted, they don't have the bitter taste that some do:

http://www.thorntons.co.uk/thumbnail/Chocolate-Toffee-Fudge/No-Added-Sugar-Chocolate/No-Added-Sugar-Chocolate/pc/2198/c/2212/2212.uts

Answer (score 1):

I think you should at least tell us where you live. 
Anyway you can try those website where they should send the chocolate to your door and that I tried and are particularly good:

http://sweetfactory.com/chocolate/sugar-free-chocolates.html

http://www.amberlynchocolates.com/sugar-free-chocolate.php

Please notice that depending on where in the world you live they may not delivery to your door.
Otherwise try this a google search.